# Problem in pushing, pulling in Sourcetree

Tags: gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree, git-push, git-pull

I have added a GitLab account in SourceTree. In my GitLab account there is no 2FA enabled. I have already created Personal Access Token in GitLab and have been using that token to authenticate my GitLab account in SourceTree. I can clone any repository from remote. But facing problem while performing push/pull. The error screenshot is attached here.

[image: Error while performing push/pull from SourceTree]

The below actions I have already done:

- Remove the credentials from Window's credential manager
- Reinstall the SourceTree
- Re-authenticate GitLab account
- A BitBucket account is added in the SourceTree. And push/pull is working as expected for BitBucket repositories.
- But it isn't working yet for GitLab repositories

What can I do now to use the SourceTree's UI Push/Pull/Fetch button functioning perfectly?

Comment: Start by doing at least one successful push from the command line.

Comment: @matt Yeah, currently I'm doing push/pull using the command line and it's fine there. But I want to use the SourceTree UI for push/pull as it will be faster for me.

Comment: Check this solution from another thread, it works greatly:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77848357/6523204