# I can't do anything(push/pull/fetch) using the GUI of SourceTree (credentalhelperselector, git-credential-manager-core)

Tags: gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

I have installed SourceTree. While installing I signed in using BitBucket account. But later on I add a GitLab account. But whenever I am going to perform any operation(push/pull/fetch) in GitLab repo from the SourceTree GUI, I am getting this error :

> warning: git-credential-manager-core was renamed to git-credential-manager
> warning: see https://aka.ms/gcm/rename for more information

Currently I'm doing the push/pull/fetch by using the cmd. But it requires providing the username and password on every operation. How can I take the benefit of using the GUI features of the SourceTree for the Git operations??

After installing the SourceTree, a CredentalHelperSelector prompt was opened, I selected the manager-core

Even I uninstall multiple times, and removed the files from the appdata and reinstall [as per this answer](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Re-How-do-I-fully-remove-SourceTree-so-that-I-can-do-a-quot/qaq-p/1449638/comment-id/36837#M36837), but it didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

1. Uninstall the SourceTree fully following the link: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Re-How-do-I-fully-remove-SourceTree-so-that-I-can-do-a-quot/qaq-p/1449638/comment-id/36837#M36837
2. Add your BitBucket account
3. Add your GitLab Account
4. While the **CredentalHelperSelector** prompt opens, select **manager** button and check the check box.
5. All done then.